# URL Rewrite for specific page, not general

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

For my site I have the following rewrite job:

```
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)  pagecategory.php?category=$1&idcat=$2
```

On another page I include an image (http://example.com/logo/15_1.png) but the rewrite rule also has effect on the img src.

How can I specify that the rewrite rule only effects the pagecategory.php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you link to pagecategory? `http://example.com/mycategory/2`?

Comment: then either exclude everything that has an 'png' (or 'jpg',..) at the end, or contains 'logo'

Comment: this `([0-9a-zA-Z]+(?<!logo))/([0-9]+)` seems to be working for excluding 'logo'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I have learned you can exclude a part in the url that matches a  (part of) string. With this knowloedge, I have another question what possible works for more future problems:  Can I make this rewrite url work for only the productcategory.php page (instead of excluding " logo" )?    I have multiple pages that look a like, but have a different name.

Comment: Did any of the provided solutions helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a regex version that *excludes* everything that contains 'logo' from the rule.

```
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+(?<!logo))/([0-9]+)  pagecategory.php?category=$1&idcat=$2
```